# subline text 3 разделения вкладок

Tags: html, sublime-text

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтоб в ST3 на одном экране отображались сразу 2 окна, чтоб не постоянно не переключаться между ними

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View > Layout в главном меню. Там можно выбрать количество столбцов.

Можно через горячие клавиши, по умолчанию shift + alt + (цифра)